# Providing a more meaningful message when an error is raised in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, error-handling, plsql

Suppose I have a PL/SQL function that selects one value from a table. If the query returns no records, I wish for the `NO_DATA_FOUND` error to propagate (so that the calling code can catch it), but with a more meaningful error message when `SQLERRM` is called.

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
FUNCTION fetch_customer_id(customer_name VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER;
    customer_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT customer_id
      INTO customer_id
      FROM CUSTOMERS
     WHERE customer_name = fetch_customer_id.customer_name;

    RETURN customer_id;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        meaningful_error_message := 'Customer named ' || customer_name || ' does not exist';
        RAISE;
END;
```

Is there a way to associate `meaningful_error_message` with the `NO_DATA_FOUND` error?

**Update:** It has been suggested that I use `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` to raise a custom error code when `NO_DATA_FOUND` is encountered. The purpose of this question was to determine if this technique could be avoided so that the calling code can catch `NO_DATA_FOUND` errors rather than a custom error code. Catching `NO_DATA_FOUND` seems more semantically correct, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'your message');`

This will return an error number -20001, and your message instead of the NO_DATA_FOUND message. Oracle has reserved the error numbers between -20001 and -210000 for user use in their applications, so you won't be hiding another Oracle error by using these numbers.

**EDIT:** `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` is specifically designed to allow you to create your own error messages. So Oracle does not have another method of allowing dynamic error messages. To further refine this you can define your own exception in the package where you define your procedure. Add the following:

```
CUSTOMER_NO_DATA_FOUND  EXCEPTION; 
EXCEPTION_INIT (CUSTOMER_NO_DATA_FOUND, -20001);
```

In your procedure code, you do the `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`, and the client code can do a
`WHEN CUSTOMER_NO_DATA_FOUND THEN` which looks better, and they still have the error message captured in `SQLERRM`.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#sthref2006

Comment: I was hoping to avoid `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` so that the calling code could catch `NO_DATA_FOUND` errors rather than the custom error codes. To me, it seems more semantically correct that way. Thank you for your response, though! :)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23030/thomas-jones-low) you can use `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`. If you also want to keep the `NO_DATA_FOUND` error on the error stack you can add TRUE as a third parameter to the function:

```
DECLARE
   l NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT NULL INTO l FROM dual WHERE 1 = 2;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN no_data_found THEN
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Meaningful Message', TRUE);
END;

ORA-20001: Meaningful Message
ORA-06512: at line 8
ORA-01403: no data found (*)
```

The line tagged (*) is the original error message.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. As I mentioned in my comment to Thomas, I was hoping to see if there was a solution that did not involve `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`. Thanks, though!